# UITextField should return a textfield of button

Tags: ios, uitextfield

**Sample:** textfield1       textfield2    textfield3   textfield4  textfield5

```
                        button
```

**Question:** 
In iOS there are 5 text fields, assume button as value 1. When button is pressed the 1st time, the value 1 should be displayed in the first text field and the button value should be incremented to 2. When the button is pressed the second time, the value 2 should be displayed in the second text field and the button value should be incremented to 3. Continue similarly for all 5 values.

Comment: This isn't a question. It's a very unclear statement. Please rephrase this into a clear question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try using tags. Setup your text fields with tags 1 to 5, then implement the view controller something like this:

```
#import "ButtonValueViewController.h"

@interface ButtonValueViewController ()
// Properties
@property (nonatomic) int buttonValue;

// Actions
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
@end

@implementation ButtonValueViewController

@synthesize buttonValue;

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialise buttonValue to 1
    self.buttonValue = 1;
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Get the textfield with the tag number the same as buttonValue
    UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:self.buttonValue];

    // Set textfield's text to buttonValue
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.buttonValue];

    // Increment buttonValue
    self.buttonValue++;
}

@end
```